# If A is associated with B, is the contrary also true?

Tags: generalized-linear-model

In general statistics, if $A$ is associated with $B$, is $B$ always associated with $A$? That is, if we get significant association for $B$ in GLM: $A \sim B + C$ with link function $f$, can we say $B$ is associated with $A$ with $p<0.05$ as well as $A$ is associated with $B$ with $p<0.05$?

I would really appreciate a good reference. The question arose from co-author feedback acknowledging the relation in one direction only.

Edit: I agree that the meaning of association should be clarified. First of all, does the concept have generally accepted and robust statistical or epidemiological definition? I think that I interpret the association to mean that there is some statistically significant relationship between two concepts which can be expressed using mathematical expression/equation.

Comment: True if you're using Pearson correlation $r$ to measure correlation:  $r_{ab} = r_{ba}.$

Comment: Also true for statistical dependence. But can you be more precise about what you mean by the word "associated"?

Comment: Right, the notion of “association” should be clarified.  It’s not true for conditional entropy, for instance.

Comment: Perhaps you mean "converse" rather than "contrary".

Comment: I think you have correctly stated a generic sense of "association," but please be aware that "statistically significant relationship" depends on the model, the significance test used, and the null hypothesis, and thereby can have multiple (and quite different) meanings in any context.  In particular, a test of a coefficient in a GLM does not suggest any natural corresponding test when you swap the response with one of the explanatory variables: the relevant model might be totally different.  That's why, as in many cases, the only general answer to your question is "it depends."

Comment: Having said that, the *intention* behind using a word like "association" is that it be symmetrical.  In a regression context, to say $Y$ is associated with $X$ means the conditional distribution of $Y$ varies with $X:$ the two variables are not independent.  That is manifestly a symmetrical relationship.  So, in this very general sense, there is no difference between the two statements--and only one p-value is involved, so that necessarily is the same, too.

Answer (score 2):

> If A is associated with B, is the contrary also true?

If the measure you used is symmetric, yes. The mutual information of $A$ and $B$ equals the mutual information of $B$ and $A$. The Pearson correlation coefficient of $A$ and $B$ equals the Pearson correlation coefficient of $B$ and $A$. However, regressing $Y$ on $X$ is not the same thing of regressing $X$ on $Y$, because [regression is not symmetric](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/77087/symmetry-of-linear-regression).

I'm not saying it can never happen, but it won't necessarily happen.